# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: php, iis-7

I am trying to open an access file through php. The code i am using is this:

```
<?php
$connStr = 'odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
.'Dbq=C:\\file.accdb;';
$dbh = new PDO($connStr);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$params = array();
$sth->execute($params);
?>
```

If i place the file in my IIS C drive, then php file opens just fine. If i try to place the file inside a network location (i have permissions in that network location) then i get the following error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: 63 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access 
 Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN 
 for process 0x16e0 Thread 0xd84 DBC 0x215b904                                                             
 Jet'.' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\update.php:56
 Stack trace:
 #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\teldir\update.php(56): PDO->__construct('odbc:Driver={Mi...')
 #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\update.php on line 56
```

In ODBC i have created a DSN and selected the file through network location.

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I think the user which executes the PHP script, doesn't have the right permissions..

Comment: i am the user who executes the script and i have permissions to this file. Do i need to have permissions to all the path?For example if my path is: \\network\groups\mygroup\file.accdb, do i need to have full access at mygroup and groups and network or just the file?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but Google gave me this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/295297/prb-error-message-0x80004005-general-error-unable-to-open-registry-key